# Return an empty array instead of null with golang for json return with gin

Tags: json, go, go-gin

I have a struct:

```
type ProductConstructed struct {
    Name string `json:"Name"`
    BrandMedals []string `json:"BRAND_MEDALS"`
}
```

When I return my object with gin:

```
func  contructproduct(c *gin.Context) {
    var response ProductConstructed 
    response.Name = "toto"

    c.JSON(200, response)
}

func main() {
    var err error
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    //gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
    r := gin.Default()
    r.POST("/constructProductGo/v1/constructProduct", contructproduct)
    r.Run(":8200") // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
}
```

It returns:

> null

instead of:

> []

How to return an empty array?

Comment: You are using struct for response instead of array of struct so current output is accurate one. It seems from your code that you want to return only one struct at a time. So instead of handling it via empty array, handle it on null.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

So the solution was to initialize it with :

```
productConstructed.BrandMedals = make([]string, 0)
```

Comment: or `productConstructed.BrandMedals = []string{}` would do too

Comment: @Seaskyways your solution is more elegant and lisible thanks

Comment: it is 100% equivalent, just different syntax

Answer (score 24):

Just to clarify why the solution above works:

`slice1` is declared, but not defined. No variable has been assigned to it yet, it equals `nil`. When serialized, it will return `null`.

`slice2` is declared and defined. It equals to an empty slice, not `nil`. When serialized, it will return `[]`.

```
var slice1 []string  // nil slice value
slice2 := []string{} // non-nil but zero-length

json1, _ := json.Marshal(slice1)
json2, _ := json.Marshal(slice2)

fmt.Printf("%s\n", json1) // null
fmt.Printf("%s\n", json2) // []

fmt.Println(slice1 == nil) // true
fmt.Println(slice2 == nil) // false
```

Go playground: https://play.golang.org/p/m9YEQYpJLdj

More info: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#declaring-empty-slices

Comment: This was a nice and simple answer. I did a `if len(records) == 0 { return []record{} }`

Comment: That's incorrect behavior since go use default values for all vars that not a pointer.
https://go.dev/play/p/lOl4w2FEHI0